# How to center items in a div without losing height of parent?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a container div with 2 spans inside it. When I try to `align-items: center` i lose the `height` and `border-radius` of the spans. I'd like them to retain   their heights and border radius, while just being centered. How can I do this?

CSS of parent div:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px 8px 10px 8px;
  height: 70px;
`;
```

CSS of child span:

```
const TextContainer = styled.span`
  padding: 8px 11px;
`;
```

Before `align-items: center`:
[image]

After `align-items: center`: [image: After align center]

Comment: If you give more information it gonna more helpful.

Comment: @zynkn if you give more information about the information you need it would be more helpful

Comment: like a blueprint what would you wanna make, there is only before and after. where is what you wanna make?

Comment: Can you please post a snippet, or at least the HTML so I can test and figure out what is wrong?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` to `span` and align items.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px 8px 10px 8px;
  height: 70px;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 11px;
  background: #f00;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Match Rank</span>
  <span>
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/83/60/50.jpg" />
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Not sure why i didn't set it to `display: flex;` before, brain lag I guess!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually due to `inline-flex` setting a vertical align of baseline.

Removing the `align-items` would change it to `stretch` but you probably don't want to do that.

**SOLUTION1**

What happens if you use ***`align-items: flex-start`***

**SOLUTION2**

Or you could try setting the vert align to top, that may fix it.

```
const TextContainer = styled.span`
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 8px 11px;
`;
```

Can you try those and let me know how it turns out ?   Thanks

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Vaibhav 's answer did the trick, thanks a lot for the input though.

Comment: Nice, glad you got it figured out.